# PHP extracting variables from list

Tags: php, api, youtube

how do I extract for example title value from following list? http://pastebin.com/11AiRCJh but with PHP, so I can save it to variable $newTitle for example.

Here is some code:

```
$searchResultLink = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=$q&key=$key&maxResults=25";
$searchResultKod = file_get_contents($searchResultLink);
//echo $searchResultKod;

$json = json_decode($searchResultKod);

$title = $json->items[0]->snippet->title;
echo $title;
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is in JSON format so use `json_decode()` on that string.

```
$json = json_decode($your_string);

$title = $json->items[0]->snippet->title;
```

This will get you the title of first item in the `items` list.

That is assuming you already have the string, if that info is on a remote server/api you'll need to use something like `file_get_contents()` to get it first.

Comment: but it says, Notice: Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: you'll have to update your question with the relevant code or else I can't help much more than that

Comment: Oh great, glad to help